# How to Set 2 different date in materialize datepicker using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

i am using [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/) template, I am trying to create 2 different default Date which is today and 2 days ago with javascript like this:

[image]

However, materialize only allow one default date using defaultDate using:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {defaultDate: new Date(),
        setDefaultDate: true });
```

which set both dates to only one default date to

[image]

is there a way to set 2 different Default dates?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it, it's assigning them manually using their Input ID

```
// check current date
var d = new Date();
// recreate new date as mm/dd/yyyy to new date then subtract 2 in day
var dayBefore = new Date( (d.getMonth()+ 1) +"/" + (d.getDate()-2) + "/" +  d.getFullYear());

// load datepicker class style from materialize
// and set default date for the cards
// getmonth() + 1 because the month start in 0 not 1
var elems = document.getElementById('FirstElement');
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', defaultDate: dayBefore ,
    setDefaultDate: true });

var elems = document.getElementById('SecondElement');
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', defaultDate: d,
    setDefaultDate: true });
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<input id="FirstElement" type="text" class="datepicker">
<label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
<input id="SecondElement" type="text" class="datepicker">
<label for="end_time">End Time</label>
```